# Xcode 11 Debugging Variables- Display all Properties -> Search for Values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

While debugging a Swift program, how can I get Xcode to make available all properties and values of all variables so I can search them for a specific string?

In the example below, I do a lot of busy guess work by running `po sender`, then `po sender.titleLabel`, then `po sender.backgroundcolor` etc. until I find the value I'm looking for.  Competing IDEs let you just search for a string ("blue" or "button1" or whatever) and display all matching variable properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is:

Starting from nothing...

[image]

Option-click the triangle to show all properties...

[image]

And then use the filter bar at the bottom. Here, I've typed "matt" in the filter bar:

[image]

If that doesn't find what you're looking for, you're just out of luck and will have to keep doing what you're doing. It's unclear what problem you're really trying to solve so it's hard to give more specific suggestions.